# Kotlin - Use an object of ListOf List as an element in another Object w/ListOf List

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a class that describes an object such that:

```
data class Item(
    var productName: String = "",
    var productId: String = "", 
    var productDesc: String = "", 
    var productPrice: String = ""
)
```

and an object which holds a variable of a ListOf Item(s):

```
object Items {
    var myItems = listOf<Item>(

        Item(
          productName:  "Item #1",
          productId: "com.example.website.products.item1",
          productDesc: "This is a description for Item #1",
          productPrice: "$5.99"
         ),

        Item(
          productName:  "Item #2",
          productId: "com.example.website.products.item2",
          productDesc: "This is a description for Item #2",
          productPrice: "$0.99"
         )

    )
}
```

This works great, I can access the List with:

```
for (myItem in Items.myItems) {
  //do this
}
```

or other similar methods.

What I have run into lately is that the list of items has grown too big and the file is becoming too large for AndroidStudio to process.

I would like to be able to make a few separate objects and then merge them into one object with a reference to each object. Not sure I am explaining this correctly, but this is what I imagine it would look like:

```
data class Item(
    var productName: String = "",
    var productId: String = "", 
    var productDesc: String = "", 
    var productPrice: String = ""
)

//Master Object with references to "sub" objects below:
object Items {
   var myItems = listOf<Item>(
      ItemsForUSA.myItems,
      ItemsForCAN.myItems
   )
}


//Object #1
object ItemsForUSA {
    var myItems = listOf<Item>(

        Item(
          productName:  "Item #1",
          productId: "com.example.website.products.item1",
          productDesc: "This is a description for Item #1",
          productPrice: "$5.99"
         ),

        Item(
          productName:  "Item #2",
          productId: "com.example.website.products.item2",
          productDesc: "This is a description for Item #2",
          productPrice: "$0.99"
         )

    )
}


//Object #2
object ItemsForCAN {
    var myItems = listOf<Item>(

        Item(
          productName:  "Item #3",
          productId: "com.example.website.products.item3",
          productDesc: "This is a description for Item #3",
          productPrice: "$2.99"
         ),

        Item(
          productName:  "Item #4",
          productId: "com.example.website.products.item4",
          productDesc: "This is a description for Item #4",
          productPrice: "$1.99"
         )

    )
}
```

This way, I could reference `Items.myItems` and get everything in both `ItemsForUSA` and `ItemsForCAN` etc..

Is this possible?

Any insight appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like you'd be better off not hardcoding this data, but storing it in a file (e.g. in JSON or proto format) and reading it in at runtime, instead.

Comment: Yeah, I am considering that as an option as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine collections with [`a.plus(b)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/plus.html) - since that's an *operator*, you can just do `a + b`.

Just bear in mind that this produces a new collection, so if you're under memory constraints, this isn't the way to go! And you'd want something like a database instead, so you can select or stream data as needed instead of holding it all in memory.

If it's just a case of your file having a huge number of lines and making Android Studio choke, you might want to consider storing your data in a text file instead (e.g. a CSV file) and place it in `assets`. Then you can read from that file at runtime and parse it into `Item`s for your list, or use it to initialise a database, etc. It'll be way easier (and more performant) to work with as a plain text file too.

(You're working with `List`s by the way, not `Array`s! They're not the same thing - there can be some overlap in how you interact with them though, `plus` is defined for both)